# Strophe MAM how to display the messages?

Tags: javascript, strophe

I have managed to use Strophe MAM to get the archived messages into the RAWInput, and display the last message(but only the last one). How do i display all the messages from the RAWInput?? But not just the last one?

And how do i extract who the message is from?

I have limited the messages to the last 5.

```
connection.mam.query("test3@macbook-pro.local", {
  "with": "test4@macbook-pro.local","before": '',"max":"5",
  onMessage: function(message) {


            console.log( $(message).text());




  },
  onComplete: function(response) {
            console.log("Got all the messages");

  }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all the messages using the `[strophe.mam.js](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/mam) plugin

Here is my working code:

```
// Retrives the messages between two particular users.

var archive = [];

var q = {
    onMessage: function(message) {
        try {
            var id = message.querySelector('result').getAttribute('id');
            var fwd = message.querySelector('forwarded');
            var d = fwd.querySelector('delay').getAttribute('stamp');
            var msg = fwd.querySelector('message');
            var msg_data = {
                id:id,
                with: Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(msg.getAttribute('to')),
                timestamp: (new Date(d)),
                timestamp_orig: d,
                from: Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(msg.getAttribute('from')),
                to: Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(msg.getAttribute('to')),
                type: msg.getAttribute('type'),
                body: msg.getAttribute('body'),
                message: Strophe.getText(msg.getElementsByTagName('body')[0])
            };
            archive.val(archive.val() + msg_data.from + ":" + msg_data.message + "\n" + msg_data.to + ":" + msg_data.message + "\n");
            archive.scrollTop(archive[0].scrollHeight - archive.height());
            console.log('xmpp.history.message',msg_data.message);
        } catch(err){
            if(typeof(err) == 'TypeError'){
                try {
                    console.log(err.stack)
                } catch(err2){
                    console.log(err,err2);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    },
    onComplete: function(response) {
        console.log('xmpp.history.end',{query:q, response:response});
    }
};

$(document).ready(function)(){
archive = $("#archive-messages");
archive.val("");
$("#to-jid").change(function() {
            $("#archive-messages").val("");
            var to = {"with": $(this).val()};
            $.extend(q, to, before, max);
            // It takes around 800ms to auto login. So after this timeout we have to retrieve the messages of particular User.
            setTimeout(function(){
            connection.mam.query(Strophe.getBareJidFromJid(connection.jid), q);
        }, 1000);
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! It works, i am just wondering the Openfire Archive has a slight delay right? Any work around to reduce that delay time?

Comment: @John Good to hear that it works. If it works you can accept the answer so that other users can easily solve this issue. And I didn't worked with Openfire yet. Right now I am using ejabberd to do archive. It doesn't have any delay. Ejabberd is very nice when compared to other XMPP servers

Comment: yup accepted the answer, do you think its a lot more difficult to use Ejabbered?? If its hard to set up, offline messages, archive, ping with Ejabbered? Because i am still tempted to switch over to Ejabberd, just not sure how much better it is than Openfire.

Comment: @John It's very easy to use Ejabberd  as per my experience. Installation and Setup is pretty much easier. You can easily configure all this offline messages, archive, ping, mam and some other configuration in ejabberd. As per my suggestion, using ejabberd doesn't makes you tough. Its pretty much better than openfire. If you through your mail id, I will send you some comparision made by me between some XMPP servers. So that you can make your own choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
connection.mam.query("Your_Id", {
  "with": "partner_id","before": '',"max":'',
  onMessage: function(message) {

console.log("Message from ", $(message).find("forwarded message").attr("from"),
                ": ", $(message).find("forwarded message body").text());

return true;

  },
  onComplete: function(response) {
            console.log("Got all the messages");

  }
    });

This will fetch all History for a user. If you want to limit, then provide max value.

Don't download strophe.mam.js(https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/mam) from github. Its not working. Please copy below strophe.mam.js file.

**strophe.mam.js**
/* XEP-0313: Message Archive Management
 * Copyright (C) 2012 Kim Alvefur
 *
 * This file is MIT/X11 licensed. Please see the
 * LICENSE.txt file in the source package for more information.
 *
 * TODO:
 * Get RSM from the reply
 * Clean remove onMessage handler afterwards
 * queryid?
 *
 */

Strophe.addConnectionPlugin('mam', {
    _c: null,
    _p: [ "with", "start", "end" ],
    init: function (conn) {
        this._c = conn;
        Strophe.addNamespace('MAM', 'urn:xmpp:mam:0');
    },
    query: function (jid, options) {
        var _p = this._p;
        var attr = {
            type:"set",
            id:jid
        };
        var mamAttr = {xmlns: Strophe.NS.MAM};
        var iq = $iq(attr).c("query", mamAttr).c('x',{xmlns:'jabber:x:data'});

        iq.c('field',{var:"FORM_TYPE"}).c('value').t("urn:xmpp:mam:0").up().up();
        for (i = 0; i < this._p.length; i++) {
            var pn = _p[i];
            var p = options[pn];
            delete options[pn];
            if (!!p) {
                var f
                iq.c('field',{var:pn}).c('value').t(p).up().up();
            }
        }
        iq.up();

        var onMessage = options["onMessage"];
        delete options['onMessage'];
        var onComplete = options["onComplete"];
        delete options['onComplete'];
        iq.cnode(new Strophe.RSM(options).toXML());

        this._c.addHandler(onMessage, Strophe.NS.MAM, "message", null);
        return this._c.sendIQ(iq, onComplete);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to retrieve all the messages is to include this line at the end of the `onMessage()` function:

`return true;`

I think the reason is that if a handler does not return `true`, it will be destroyed after the first time it is called.